# Paypal - where can I find "Encrypted Payment Settings" in sandbox account?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal

I created the sandbox account, in this account I created an account for seller and for buyer. Now I would need to get **Encrypted Payment Settings**, but when I click on PROFILE link in the dashboard, I see just inputs for my name...

I am trying to follow this tutorial: http://www.fortytwo.gr/blog/14/Using-Paypal-with-Rails

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Paypal's not the most user friendly website.  The tutorial you're following is quite old and they've changed the website workflow considerably since then.

Go to Test Accounts, create a business account if you didn't already.  Select the newly created business account and click on "Enter Sandbox Test Site".  You'll be redirected to a new login screen, enter your test business account login credentials.  Now you'll see a full fledged Paypal business account.  Click on profile and you'll see **Encrypted Payment Settings** there.